# Get product by selected category in ordering by category count

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I want to get product by category filter and order by category count belong to product.

Two table - product and pro_cat

[image]

[image]

customer filter the category id 10 and 15 than product list be order by number of category belongs to each product. For ex. Product id 1 belong to 4 categories so it will come first that so on.

```
SELECT product.id
     , product.name 
  FROM product 
  JOIN pro_cat 
    ON product.id = pro_cat.product_id 
 where category_id in (10,15) 
 group 
    by product.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

do the join between  the two table you could use count(*)

```
SELECT product.id
       , product.name 
FROM product 
JOIN pro_cat ON product.id = pro_cat.product_id 
where category_id in (10,15) 
group by product.id;
order by count(*) DESC
```